# installation of node fails because of unsufficient priviliges to enter the folder

Tags: node.js

Trying to install latest version of node on win10, I run the msi install package and halfway through the installation it tells me that it does not have sufficient permissions and that it needs administrator permissions. I cancel the install and try to run it again as administrator however it seems that for .msi file types win10 does not offer to run as administrator.

It offers

```
instal

repair

uninstall
```

How can i install node? I wanted to update my current node version to latest, should I perhaps uninstall first and then try to install?

Comment: thanks, i downloaded msi for some reason, but have now been able to make it run as admin after editing regedit

Comment: actually msi still has problems even when run as admin, where do you find exe installer? its not available here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. install it somewhere else and use it from there
2. install it somewhere else and move it later
3. use the ZIP package and move the files where you want
4. download the EXE file
5. install from source
6. use nvm

See files in:

- https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.9.0/win-x64/

and:

- https://nodejs.org/dist//v7.9.0/

nvm for Windows:

- https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: is there an exe installer I can run?

Comment: @maxit No as far as I know. But you can get node.exe from https://nodejs.org/dist//v7.9.0/win-x64/

Comment: what should I do with node.exe? just drop it in the old folder where old node version is? is that all thats needed for the update?